# Windows 8: How to detect when a UI element is dragged off the screen

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How to detect when a UI element is dragged off the screen for a Windows 8 store app.

I have a list of items that are displayed to the user.
I want the user to flick items off the screen that he/she wants to remove from their view.

Thanks,
Scott Nimrod

Comment: When it moves beyond CoreWindow.Bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can manipulate your object using ManipulationDelta event & CompositeTransform. You then need to check objects cordinates relative to CoreWindow using TransformToAncestor method, just to make sure that you don't transform object out of your window.